# Predict class of items according to structure

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have a problem where I have some items that are related in space (Ex: I have a dataset of coordinates of where eyes, mouth and nose labelled on an image of that contains a face and I want to predict given only coordinates what are eyes,nose and mouth). I'd like to create a model to learn general relation between objects and classify them.

What model should I use, what kind of problem is it?

Comment: the task can be solved using other techniques than full-blown ML models. For example faces have a certain symmetry/analogy which is more-or-less standard in every person. So the nose is at some ratio down from the eyes and mouth is a certain ratio down from the nose. Given these one can very easily identify the features

Comment: do you have an example of implementation of such a method?

Comment: I have used HAAR cascades using the Viola-Jones-Lienhart method to detect features of faces (eg openCV). You can look it up. Then after some features have been found other features which are at certain distances from main features can be estimated as well